# How to extract response after posting data to a remote payment gateway server?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, curl, simplexml

How to write PHP parse code eg.  testrec.php to extract and save the transaction response variable 'response_code' ? How do you do this successfully using  DOM, curl , Soap or simplexml. Coding is in php.

$resulturl = http://esewa.com.np/epay/transrec?pid=AddFund-C-11970239-9625960&amt=100&scd=nprhosting&rid=00C3LF0

Opening this url gives Success reponse. 
When you view source code you can see this xml structure

```
<response>
<response_code>
Success
</response_code>
</response>
```

Please suggest the right code. Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. While we're happy to help with *specific* problems you've encountered, this isn't a code-writing service or general tutorial site, so you'll need to have a go at finding some basic introductions elsewhere. If you get some code together but get stuck on some specific detail, come back and we can help you figure it out. Have a read through the [help] if you haven't already, as it has some tips on how to write questions which will be well-received and help us to help you. Good luck. :)